# remove previous data in div tag and bind new data to same div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

> hi,here i want to remove data from div and rebind new data to that div.
>   How can i achive this one.here in div tag am diaplaying full calender with some events.
>   here i want to delete data of that div and rebind new events to that same div tag

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: dataString,
    url: "ViewEvents.aspx/GetState",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
             },
             //select: selectDate,
             eventClick: updateEvent,
             droppable: false,
             draggable: false,
             disableDragging: true,
             timeFormat: 'H:mm',
             selectable: true,
             selectHelper: true,
             eventTextColor: 'Yellow',
             eventBackgroundColor: 'purple',
             events:
                 $.map(data.d, function (item, i) {
                     //  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', item);
                     var sdate = item.StartDate
                     var sdatesplit = sdate.split("/");
                     var sm = sdatesplit[0];
                     var sm = sm - 1;
                     var sd = sdatesplit[1];
                     var sy = sdatesplit[2];
                     var syearsplit = sy.split(" ");
                     var edate = item.EndDate;
                     var edatesplit = edate.split("/");
                     var em = edatesplit[0];
                     var em = em - 1;
                     var ed = edatesplit[1];
                     var ey = edatesplit[2];
                     var eyearsplit = ey.split(" ");
                     var stime = item.EventStarttime;
                     var stimesplit = stime.split(":");
                     var etime = item.EventEndtime;
                     var etimesplit = etime.split(":");
                     var event = new Object();
                     event.id = item.EventID;
                     event.start = new Date(syearsplit[0], sm, sd, stimesplit[0], stimesplit[1]);
                     event.end = new Date(eyearsplit[0], em, ed, etimesplit[0], etimesplit[1]);
                     event.title = item.EventName;
                     event.allDay = false;
                     return event;

                })
        });
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

Comment: `$('#calander').html('');` should clear it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#calendar').empty();
```

Or

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
```

See the [doc](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/destroy/) of your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear your grid by `$('#calendar').html("");`
To rebind your grid you can use

```
$('#calendar').append('yourelements')` or 

$('#calendar').add('yourelements')
```

`